# How to close an AlertDialog in android

Tags: android

I am developing a sample android app that display numbers(1-to-5) in a Alert Dialog and the numbers change after one second. Now I want to close the AlertDialog after 5-seconds. How I close the alert dialog box. You can check my code that I have developed so far. Please help me in this regard. I would greatly appreciate help.

```
    timeView = new TextView(this);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


            builder.setView(timeView);
            builder.setTitle("Time"); 
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();




timeView.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()

            {

                switch(timeSecond)
                {

                     case 0:timeView.setText("5"); 
                     timeSecond++;
                     break;

                     case 1:timeView.setText("4"); 
                     timeSecond++;
                     break;

                     case 2:timeView.setText("3"); 
                     timeSecond++;
                     break;

                     case 3:timeView.setText("2"); 
                     timeSecond++;
                     break;

                     case 4:timeView.setText("1"); 
                     timeSecond++;
                     break;


                }
                if(timeSecond!=5)
                {
                    timeView.postDelayed(this,1000);

                }

                else
                {
                    //Here I want to close the Alert Dialog

                }

            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just assign it to a reference and call dismiss on it?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Hello"); 
builder.setMessage("Hello Android");
builder.setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
...
if(conditionTrue)
{
    //Here close the Alert Dialog
    dialog.dismiss()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
....
dialog.dismiss()
```

will close the dialog.

**EDIT**: For your code above, I suggest the alternative:

```
    if (!conditionTrue) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Hello"); 
        builder.setMessage("Hello Android");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }
```

No need to show the dialog if you want to dismiss it.

Comment: In your code it would be weird: you just opened the dialog (builder.show()), why would you want to close it right after? The screen would probably flicker, that's not great. You'd better check on your condition before you show the dialog